# i want move file from one location to another but source and destination folder automatically ask and file name taken from cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub copy_and_move_selectedfiles()

Dim sourcefolder As FileDialog
Dim destinationfolder As FileDialog
Dim mypath1 As String
Dim mypath2 As String
Dim myfile As FileDialog
Dim FSO

              
     

Set sourcefolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 
              With sourcefolder
              .Title = " Select Source folder"
              .AllowMultiSelect = False
              If .Show = -1 Then
              mypath1 = .SelectedItems(1)
              Else
              End
              End If
              End With
              
Set destinationfolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 
              With destinationfolder
              .Title = " Select Destination folder"
              .AllowMultiSelect = False
              If .Show = -1 Then
              mypath2 = .SelectedItems(1)
              Else
              End
              End If
              End With
              
              Range("A3").Select
              Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
              Set myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
              myfile = .SelectedItems(1)
             

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
              
              FSO.movefile sourcefolder, destinationfolder
              Loop

End Sub
```

i write some code its like first asking source folder and asking destination folder and then file which is move taken from cell and afteer file moved its continue until cell get empty.

Comment: I think your code would be much clearer if you used indentions properly.

Answer (score 1):

- Assume that the file name is in col A and starts from A3.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub copy_and_move_selectedfiles()
    Dim sourcefolder As FileDialog
    Dim destinationfolder As FileDialog
    Dim mypath1 As String
    Dim mypath2 As String
    Dim myfile As FileDialog
    Dim FSO
    Set sourcefolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With sourcefolder
        .Title = " Select Source folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            mypath1 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set destinationfolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With destinationfolder
        .Title = " Select Destination folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            mypath2 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Dim c As Range
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    For Each c In Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If FSO.FileExists(mypath1 & c.Value) Then
            FSO.MoveFile mypath1 & c.Value, mypath2 & c.Value
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

*Update:*

> Question: i just want put kani in a3 cell whatever extension availble in A3 cell name (Kani) its need to move

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub copy_and_move_selectedfiles()
    Dim sourcefolder As FileDialog
    Dim destinationfolder As FileDialog
    Dim mypath1 As String
    Dim mypath2 As String
    Dim myfile As FileDialog
    Dim FSO
    Set sourcefolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With sourcefolder
        .Title = " Select Source folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            mypath1 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set destinationfolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With destinationfolder
        .Title = " Select Destination folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            mypath2 = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Dim c As Range, FileList, i As Long
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    FileList = GetFiles(mypath1)
    If Not IsArray(FileList) Then Exit Sub
    Dim bMove as Boolean
    For Each c In Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        bMove = False
        For i = 1 To UBound(FileList)
            If StrComp(c.Value, FileList(i, 2), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                FSO.MoveFile mypath1 & FileList(i, 1), mypath2 & FileList(i, 1)
                bMove = True
            End If
        Next
        c.Offset(0,1).Value = IIf(bMove, "Moved", "Not Moved")
    Next c
End Sub

Function GetFiles(ByVal sPath As String) As Variant
    Dim FSO, objFolder, objFile, aFiles(), i As Long
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
        Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
        ReDim aFiles(1 To objFolder.Files.Count, 1 To 2)
        i = 1
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            aFiles(i, 1) = objFile.Name
            aFiles(i, 2) = FSO.GetBaseName(objFile)
            i = i + 1
        Next objFile
    End If
    If i = 0 Then
        GetFiles = ""
    Else
        GetFiles = aFiles
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but fso.movefile line shows some error (file not found),i need all kind of file format to move not only pdf.please support me.

Comment: I have updated the code. Adding `FileExists` to check if the file is exist. You should make sure the file name in column A is correct. The code doesn't limit the file type.

Comment: i put file name(Kani) in A3 cell, (Kani) file inside the folder it was pdf document ,   but file not move, cannot findout code run successfully any popup not come, please support me

Comment: A filename includes two parts: base name and extension name.  Do you think `Kani` is a full filename? eg. If it is Excel, it could be Kani.xlsx. If it is Word file, it could be Kani.docx.

Comment: its moved but i put Kani.pdf in A3 cell, i just want put kani in a3 cell whatever extension availble in A3 cell name (Kani)  its need to move, please support.

Comment: You didn't mention it in your post. Is there anything else left?

Comment: no sir, thankyou so much

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: sir i have only one issue if files moved adjacent cell show moved and not moved adjacenet cell show not moved, please shall you send that code line, this is last one sir.

Comment: See the updated code.